# Associate Firebase Storage with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, backend

I am making a specimen inventorying android app in Kotlin using Google Firebase.
 I use the firebase Realtime Datebase to store the specimen details & use firebase storage to store a picture of the specimen.

Eventually I will want to pull all of this data into the app to browse.
**My Question:** What is the best way to link the specimen's details in Realtime db to it's associated picture in Storage?

my code

RockEntry.kt

```
package com.inven.rock_stock

import android.util.Log
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import java.util.*


class RockEntry {
    var name = ""
    var purchDate = ""
    var local = ""
    var mine = ""
    var weight = ""
    var paid = ""
    var asking = ""
    var description = ""
    var dimensions = ""
    var specimenNumber = ""
    var Uid = ""
    var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    var ref = database.getReference("Rocks")

    
constructor(name:String,purchDate:String,local:String,mine:String,
                    weight:String,dimensions:String,paid:String,asking:String,
                    description:String,Uid:String){

        this.name = name
        this.purchDate = purchDate.toString()
        this.local = local
        this.mine = mine
        this.weight = weight
        this.dimensions = dimensions
        this.paid = paid
        this.asking = asking
        this.description = description
        this.Uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

    }
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.inven.rock_stock

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.File
import java.net.URI

var CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 0
var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
var ref = database.getReference("Rocks")
private var mStorageRef: StorageReference? = null


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = "MyActivity"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("ImagesBB")

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        button.setOnClickListener {
            makeQuery()
        }



        imageBtn.setOnClickListener {
            takePicture()
        }
    }


    private fun makeQuery(){
        var name = name.text.toString()
        var purchDate = purchDate.toString()
        var local = locality.text.toString()
        var mine = mine.text.toString()
        var weight = weight.text.toString()
        var dimensions = dimensions.text.toString()
        var paid = paid.text.toString()
        var asking = asking.text.toString()
        var description = description.text.toString()

        if (!name.isBlank()) {
            ref.child(name.toLowerCase()).setValue(
                RockEntry(
                    name,
                    purchDate,
                    local,
                    mine,
                    weight,
                    paid,
                    asking,
                    dimensions,
                    description
                )
            )
        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Type in a name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }
    }


    private fun takePicture() {
        CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 222
        val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        try {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            // display error state to the user
        }
    }    

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {
            CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    val imageBitmap = data.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
                    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
                    val datar = baos.toByteArray()
                    mStorageRef!!.putBytes(datar)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Linking' a FireBase Storage file to your Realtime Database can be accomplished by either

1. getting the location where a file lives in FireBase storage, via
   toString() on the storage reference

   or
2. getting a URL where you can download the file, via the .downloadUrl function.

    Either of these options can then be stored as text into a Realtime Database 'entry'.

   code example:

   ```
     yourStorageBase?.putFile(element)?.addOnSuccessListener   {
       yourStorageBase?.downloadUrl?.addOnSuccessListener { downloadUri ->
                  // #1 
                  var filepath = yourStorageBase.toString()
                  // #2
                  var downloadLink = downloadUri.toString()                                             
       }
     }
   ```

Note:
If the following code is used within a function, you may 'prematurely' return to the caller before the picture has finished uploading, meaning you can't use the 'links' immediately. You can write a coroutine to ensure the IO has time to complete.

Answer (score 0):

User `RecyclerView` to load all data in your app using live model class with data adapter.

User `DataSnapShot` in firebase to get all of the child nodes from a parent.

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase DB, You have `specimen` which holds a number of Specimen, then you need to have one `picture` node as a child of each `specimen` node. When you upload the picture to `Firebase Storage` fetch its URL and insert it to the `picture` node under that particular Specimen.

Comment: I think this is more where I was heading with the question, thank you.
Do you have a code example of this? the concept makes sense but I don't know how to go about storing the url or querying it